# JQuery colorbox to print preview

Tags: jquery, printing

I am new to using JQuery.
I am trying to print preview some part of JSF page and then print it.
And I can not directly print part of the page as requirement.
Can I able to do preview of some part of page like popup it using color box and then print that popped content using print media?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to do it using Colorbox of JQuery but still simple issue is ... I can't put any link dynamically on that popup box to print it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
      var a = "<tr><td><a href='#'>Print it</a></td></tr>";
      a = $('#printable').html();
      $("#button").colorbox({html:a, width:"75%", height:"75%"});
    });
    </script>
```